# Android Beginner: Empty Edit Text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am creating an app which divides one number by another number. I have tried to add code to display a dialog when there is an empty edit text, but the app forcecloses. Here is my code.

```
public class KdCalculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText kills;
    EditText deaths;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kd_activity);

        Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonCalculate);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

        kills = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextKills);
        deaths = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextDeaths);

    }

    public void onClick(View paramView)
      { 
          boolean invalid = false;

          String str1 = kills.getText().toString();
          String str2 = deaths.getText().toString();

          if (str1.equals("") || str2.equals(""))
          {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Number")
                .setMessage("Please enter a number for both kills and deaths!")
                .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
                .show();
              invalid = true;
          }

          double d1 = Double.parseDouble(str2);
          double d2 = Double.parseDouble(str1);

          if ((d1 == 0.0D) || (d2 == 0.0D))
          {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Invalid Number")
            .setMessage("Please enter a number different than 0 for both kills and deaths!")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
              invalid = true;
          }
          double d3 = d2 / d1;
          DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          String str3 = "Your K/D Ratio is : " + localDecimalFormat.format(d3);

          if(!invalid){
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("K/D Ratio")
            .setMessage(str3)
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
          }
          invalid = false;
        }


}
```

the logcat error is:

```
05-27 11:43:53.327: W/dalvikvm(6090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020b80)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at com.blackops2.KdCalculator.onClick(KdCalculator.java:53)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2411)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-27 11:43:53.357: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your `EditText` are empty you're still parsing the empty `Strings` from those `EditText` as your code continues to be executed after you show the `AlertDialog`, instead you should return from the `onClick` method to stop any calculations(when the `EditText` are empty or aren't filled):

```
public void onClick(View paramView) { 
          String str1 = kills.getText().toString();
          String str2 = deaths.getText().toString();

          if (str1.equals("") || str2.equals("")) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Number")
                .setMessage("Please enter a number for both kills and deaths!")
                .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
                .show();
                return;   
          }
          double d1 = Double.parseDouble(str2);
          double d2 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
          if ((d1 == 0.0D) || (d2 == 0.0D)) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Invalid Number")
            .setMessage("Please enter a number different than 0 for both kills and deaths!")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
            return;
          }
          double d3 = d2 / d1;
          DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          String str3 = "Your K/D Ratio is : " + localDecimalFormat.format(d3);

          new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("K/D Ratio")
            .setMessage(str3)
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try logging the values of `str1` & `str2` before you call `Double.parseDouble(String)`; you can use `Log.d(String, String)` to do that.

According to the stack trace, one of the values cannot be turned into a number.

What I would normally do is to put any number formatting call into a `try...catch` block - there are many errors that can come out of this type of operation. This may be the most successful way of avoiding any further crashes in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
```

And just to mention try checking the String str1 and str2, and be cautious.. Double dont give divide by zero error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this one...

```
public class KdCalculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{    
    double d1 = 0.0;
    double d2 = 0.0;    
    EditText kills;
    EditText deaths;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kd_activity);

        Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonCalculate);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

        kills = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextKills);
        deaths = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextDeaths);

    }

    public void onClick(View paramView)
      { 
          boolean invalid = false;

          String str1 = kills.getText().toString();
          String str2 = deaths.getText().toString();

          if (str1.equals("") || str2.equals(""))
          {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Number")
                .setMessage("Please enter a number for both kills and deaths!")
                .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
                .show();
              invalid = true;
          }

          d1 = Double.parseDouble(str2);
          d2 = Double.parseDouble(str1);

          if ((d1 == 0.0D) || (d2 == 0.0D))
          {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Invalid Number")
            .setMessage("Please enter a number different than 0 for both kills and eaths!")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
              invalid = true;
          }
          double d3 = d2 / d1;
          DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          String str3 = "Your K/D Ratio is : " + localDecimalFormat.format(d3);

          if(!invalid){
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("K/D Ratio")
            .setMessage(str3)
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
          }
          invalid = false;
        }
}
```

And make sure your input for in the calculator have something like this 2.0 or 2.2 or etc (double format) don't use comma...